# Android: Linking to URL in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the Navigation Components library for my Navigation Drawer. I want one item in said drawer to link to an external Website. The [offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) doesn't say anything about external links. How do I implement that?

I could create a temporary fragment and navigate to that first but this solution is not very elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Calls `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` internally to connect destinations to menu items - this is how a new destination is launched when you click a menu item. Navigation supports `<activity>` destinations, allowing you to start an activity when clicking on a menu item. You'd add an activity destination to your graph that uses the same id as your menu item:

```
<activity
  android:id="@+id/nav_login_activity"
  app:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
  app:data="https://www.your_url_here.com"/>
```

Then the default `setupWithNavController` will call `startActivity` for you.